# How to assign NSString within NSString using objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I need to apply `NSString` values like below

```
NSString *parse = @"http://xyz?%@%@name=%@&age=%@";

NSString *name_val = namestring;  // assigned string value I am getting from storage 
NSString *age_val = agestring;
```

I need to `assign` like below

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:parse,name_val,age_val];
```

If I do like below I can get exact `URL string`

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:parse,name_val.text,age_val.text];
```

Please give me a good solution for my question

Comment: Will you give an example with a url which you want to create.

Comment: I'm confused, your `stringWithFormat` has two arguments, while your format has 4, if you just remove two arguments from the format, or add to to stringWithFormat then the first example `NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:parse,name_val,age_val];` works as expected.

Comment: No, Actually If I am assigning UITextfield values with parse mean, Its exactly applaying at parse" %@" place but If assign, Three sting into single NSString formation, Its not applaying properly on parse "%@" place.

Comment: I am sorry I do not understand the issue. where in your question is the UITextField? both Age and Name are NSStrings as per your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have a differing number of arguments in your format:

`http://xyz?%@%@name=%@&age=%@`

This format is looking for 4 Objects.

Changing the format to `http://xyz?name=%@&age=%@` with your format works as expected:

```
    NSString *parse = @"http://xyz?name=%@&age=%@";

    NSString *name_val = @"name";
    NSString *age_val = @"99";

    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:parse,name_val,age_val];
    printf("%s", [url UTF8String]);
```

returns:

```
http://xyz?name=name&age=99
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you hoss!